# Java net URL is not working properly, messing HTTP

Tags: java, http, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using Kafka with Avro and Schema Registry.
While publishing a message to Kafka, the avro serializer uses java.net.URL and do a POST to register the Avro schema at the schema registry. When the schema is big, the HTTP request breaks, the socket content gets messed up. I'm not sure if this relates somehow to Mac.

In one terminal I used NC and executed:

`nc -lv 8102`

On my ide (IntelliJ) and also on the command line, I executed:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var url = new URL("http://localhost:8102/subjects/local.something-something/versions");
        var connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java/11.0.11");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "67193");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        var os = connection.getOutputStream();
        var body = new byte[67193];
        Arrays.fill(body, (byte) 'a');
        os.write(body);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        connection.getResponseCode();
    }
}
```

and the output of NC had (I removed some 'a's for easily visualization):

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaPOST /subjects/local.something-something/versions HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/11.0.11
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Host: localhost:8102
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 67193

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Which is invalid and with that the schema registry returns 400

I'm using *Java 11* *adoptOpenJdk*, tried also with *oracle* JDK and *Correto*, no success.

Any ideas?

- I can't throw out URL, it's embedded in kafka-schema-registry-client
- I used *curl* to replicate the request, no issue there.

Comment: 'setDoOutput(true)` and `setRequestMethod("POST")` both do the same thing. Don't set the content-length. It is set automatically for you. `doInput(true)` is the default, but you aren't doing any input. Don't throw away the response code: print it. `flush()` before `close()` is redundant.

Comment: I've used quite large schemas before and it works fine... Maybe you can share your own schema so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Workaroud: If I set the JVM to use ipv4, it works as expected, not sure what's going on with ipv6 on Mac.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the Schema Registry project publishes a Java client as a Maven/Gradle dependency

Answer (score 1):

I've found a quick workaround, I set the jvm to use ipv4, the problem goes away.

On Gradle looks like:

```
    jvmArgs '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true'
```

Comment: Faced the same issue... this fix worked for me. This should be marked as the correct answer